# App to OCR pre-existing PDFs?

Tags: pdf, adobe-reader, ocr

I am in grad school and have a samsung galaxy tablet that I primarily use for reading and annotating PDFs. Many of these docs are scanned book chapters and have not been run through OCR before I download them to my tablet. I'd like to be able to run them through an OCR app so I can search the text. On my PC I use Acrobat Pro, which has this feature built in, but there doesn't seem to be anything comparable available for Android. I use EasyPDF Reader Pro to read and annotate PDFs on my tablet, and really like it, but it does not have an OCR feature. All of the OCR apps I've found on Google Play and by searching online seem to be geared toward recognizing text in photos and some will output a PDF, but none seem to take an existing PDF as an input. I suppose I could just convert the docs on my PC and reload them from there to the tablet, but this is a hassle and seems to defeat the purpose of having a tablet. Any suggestions on an app I've missed, or any OCR developers out there who want to cook something up that would be really helpful to all of us grad students?